# Give url path in woocommerce single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have given the a url path for image in wordpress using maya theme of woocommerce and the image is not showing the image path looks like

```
<img title="Adidas-H111-2" alt="Adidas-H111-2" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://localhost/alphatest/wp-content/uploads/http://localhost/webservice/ap/upload_images/Adidas/Hard/H111/Adidas-H111-2.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
```

how can I remove the part

```
http://localhost/alphatest/wp-content/uploads/
```

I am using maya theme and woocommerce plugin in wordpress. the full code is like

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Thumbnails
 */

global $post, $woocommerce;
?>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <?php   
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $small_thumbnail_size = apply_filters('single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail');
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_status'   => null,
            'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
            'post__not_in'  => array($thumb_id),
            'post_mime_type'=> 'image',
            'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
            'order'         => 'ASC'
        );
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) :
            $loop = 0;
            $columns = apply_filters('woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3);
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) :

                if (get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_woocommerce_exclude_image', true)==1) continue;

                $loop++;

                $_post = & get_post( $attachment->ID );
                $url = wp_get_attachment_url($_post->ID);

                $post_title = esc_attr($_post->post_title);
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, $small_thumbnail_size);


                echo '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$post_title.'" rel="thumbnails" class="zoom ';
                if ($loop==1 || ($loop-1)%$columns==0) echo 'first';
                if ($loop%$columns==0) echo 'last';
                echo '">'.$image.'</a>';

            endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add Double Slash (//)Instead of the Domain name. Example:

```
http://www.google.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/image.png
```

will be as:

```
//wp-content/uploads/2013/10/image.png
```